# Nothing provides python needed by mssql-server-is

Tags: sql-server, rhel, sql-server-2019

I'm trying to install SQL Server Integration Services on RHEL 8. I have SQL Server 2019 (version v15) installed and running successfully, but when I try and follow this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-ssis?view=sql-server-ver15#RHEL

The RHEL 8 repo doesn't have the `mssql-server-is` package in it, and using the RHEL 7 repo throws this error:

> Error:  Problem: conflicting requests
>     - nothing provides python needed by mssql-server-is-15.0.2000.5-4.x86_64 (try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)

I have both Python2 and Python 3 installed, and when I run this:

```
alternatives --config python
```

I see that `/usr/bin/python2` is selected

Any ideas how I can get SSIS installed for RHEL 8 and SQL Server 2019?

Answer (score 0):

I could install it by downloading the rpm and then installing it using `--nodeps` option as below:

```sh
sudo yum download mssql-server-is
sudo rpm -Uvh --nodeps mssql-server-is*rpm
```

Worked pretty smooth for me.